# I can't install my app to iOS 4.2.1

Tags: ios4

all.
I created new iPhone app on XCode 4.2.
But this app can't install to iOS 4.2.1.
Is there any idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any error messages?

How are you trying to install it?

Do you have the same problem with debug and release builds?

A bit more information might help!